# Queue and While loop memory exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, queue

I can't seem to understand why this throws a memory exception. When queueing the "safe" neighbour cells I get a memory exception. Any idea's why and what would cause this?

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

        if( chunk.tiles[x,y] != 0 || visited[x,y] != 1 ){ //air or already visited

            _currentIsland = new byte[ 10, 10 ];

            Queue<Vector2> toCheck = new Queue<Vector2>();
            toCheck.Enqueue( new Vector2(x,y) );

            while( toCheck.Count > 0 )
            {
                Vector2 curr = toCheck.Dequeue();

                int[] rowNbr = {-1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  1, 1, 1};
                int[] colNbr = {-1,  0,  1, -1,  1, -1, 0, 1};

                // Mark this cell as visited
                _currentIsland[x,y] = 1;
                visited[x,y] = 1;

                // Recur for all connected neighbours
                for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
                {
                    if ( isSafe ((int)curr.x + rowNbr [k], (int)curr.y + colNbr [k], visited ))
                        {
                            Vector2 n = new Vector2( curr.x  + rowNbr[k], curr.y + colNbr[k] );
                            toCheck.Enqueue(n);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if( _currentIsland.Length > 0 )
                    islands.Add( _currentIsland );

            }
        }
    }

    bool isSafe( int x, int y, byte[,] visited )
    {
        return (InScope (x, y) && visited [x, y] == 0 && chunk.tiles[x,y] > 0 );
    }
```

Thanks, C.

Comment: Prefer that someone to point out what's wrong with this question rather than just mark it down

Comment: Can you give me details about the exact exception you are getting (type, message, stack trace)?

Comment: Also can you post the code for `isSafe`?  Since you could end up putting up to 8 vectors in your queue for each vector dequeued this has the possibility of growing out of control if `isSafe` mostly returns true.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory
System.Collections.Generic.Queue1[UnityEngine.Vector2].SetCapacity (Int32 new_size)
System.Collections.Generic.Queue1[UnityEngine.Vector2].Enqueue (Vector2 item)
MeshGenerator.FindIslands () (at Assets/Scripts/MeshGenerator.cs:130)
GridManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/GridManager.cs:325)` here's the exception, thanks. edited question with isSafe method too

Comment: I assume that `InScope` with return false if (x,y) is outside of the (0,0) to (9,9) square, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are not keeping track of which neighbors you look at in the queue.

So to start off you're at (0,0) and that could add the following vectors to the queue

(1,0), (0,1), and (1,1)

Now for (1,1) it will look at (0,0), but `isSafe` will return false because you set vistied[0,0] to 1. but it would also add (1,0) and (0,1) which do not have visited set to 1 and then will in turn each add (1,1) and so on.  Basically you need to keep track of which neighors you have seen.  I'm guessing you need to change the following line

```
visited[x,y] = 1;
```

to

```
vistited[curr.x,curr.y] = 1;
```

But I'm not completely sure about the intent of your code, but that's why it could run out of memory putting the same vector values on the queue over and over again.

Comment: Typical oversight on my behalf, thanks for spotting that. It's solved the memory exception but the code is fundamentally wrong :( The intention is to find and store all islands that are in my grid.